# Calling the same function in many different classes

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, arduino

In an attempt to simplify my code I'm looking to use arrays in which a number of objects can be stored, after which functions in those objects can be called.

I have created a number of classes with (partly) the same member functions. Of course those functions have different implementation. I hope to put those objects in a single array, after which I can iterate over it calling those functions.

What I have is a number of sensors, let's call them Sensor1, Sensor2 and Sensor3. All of them have a function called readSensor(), and a function called sensorData(). (The first takes a reading of the sensor, the second returns a line of html - in my actual software there are like 10-12 sensors and 4 such functions, hence my hope to simplify the code and make adding sensors easier).

So what I'm looking to do is something like this:

```
Sensor1 sensor1;
Sensor2 sensor2;
Sensor3 sensor3;
byte nSensors = 3;

(type?) *sensorList[nSensors] // list of pointers to the sensors - don't know how to declare this.

void setup() { // yes, this is for Arduino.
  sensorList[0] = &sensor1; // store the pointers to the class objects.
  sensorList[1] = &sensor2;
  sensorList[2] = &sensor3;
}

void readSensors () {
  for (int i=1, i<nSnesors, i++) {
    sensorList[i]->readSensor();
  }
}
```

This way I can read all the sensors, without having to write out all of them and hoping I don't forget any down the line. Makes the code a lot shorter and I can add sensors in a single place. This array is only to be used for the functions that all sensors have (same name albeit in different implementation - this are different sensors after all). The objects have some sensor-specific functions as well, which are to be called directly when needed.

Would this even be possible? If so, how?

Comment: A sensor interface (base class) maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply can use runtime polymorphism for the job.

Example:

```
class SensorBase
{   
    public:
    virtual void readSensor() = 0;
    virtual void getData(char*) = 0;
};  

class Sensor1: public SensorBase
{   
    void readSensor() { std::cout << "read for Sensor1 called" << std::endl; }
    void getData(char* ptr) { std::cout << "get for Sensor1 called" << std::endl; }
};  

class Sensor2: public SensorBase
{   
    void readSensor() { std::cout << "read for Sensor2 called" << std::endl; }
    void getData(char* ptr) { std::cout << "get for Sensor2 called" << std::endl; }
};  

// Static allocate objects, new is not a good idea for small embedded devices 
// cause of significant overhead. Global objects are typically a design problem,
// but small embedded systems have different requirements ;)

Sensor1 sensor1;
Sensor2 sensor2;

// lets have array to objects, statically allocated
SensorBase* arr[] = { &sensor1, &sensor2 };


int main()
{   
    char htmlString[256];

    for ( auto ptr: arr )
    {   
        ptr->readSensor();
        ptr->getData( htmlString );
    }   
}
```

You have to remove the content of the example functions to your needs. std::cout is only used here to let the app run with visible output as an example how the things work.

You use a `setup` method in your code. That is maybe a good idea on bigger systems, but not on avr! If you use static allocation as in my given example, your code will be smaller and faster. And you can speed up it more, if you give the compiler some hints to store some of your data fields or classes in flash. For that topic please consider `#include <avr/pgmspace.h>`

Maybe you have to write your classes with `constexpr` constructors to be able to store data in flash. Attention must be payed by using virtual methods: gcc can NOT store them in flash. This is an very old bug/design problem and wastes a lot of ram of your small device. One reason to switch to arm devices! See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43745. That makes avr gcc unusable if you need a lot of polymorphic classes in your code. This bug will NOT be fixed!

Comment: The setup() and loop() is the default way of the Arduino IDE which I use - the code runs on ESP8266 so size is not much of an issue. This solution looks like what I need - going to try to understand what's going on and then try it out (also because this are actually library classes making it again a bit more complex). Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: @Wouter: If you have a array defined somewhere and fill the values inside the setup method, your program size will increase in flash and ram usage. So I prefer for small embedded systems to use fully static global definitions. All data will be copied before main starts and no additional code must be written. That has nothing to do with arduino but how and when data in variables become valid. The c-library startup code provides the necessary  code already. So you have no need to write your own copy code for that as shown in my example.

Comment: Implemented - works perfectly, thanks! It seems to have shaved some 10-20kB from my code in the process, that's good, though I have room: I'm at about 370 kB and am happy to go to just over 500 kB (can go to 1 MB but then easy OTA updates are not possible any more).

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible by use of [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)).

You can define a base class (i.e. `Sensor`) and child classes (i.e. `Sensor1`, `Sensor2` and `Sensor3`), where `Sensor` declares a method `readSensor()`, and all of the 3 child classes implement this method, but they can do this in different ways. That way you can create an array with elements of type `Sensor` and call this method on each element, which then calls the implemented method of the child classes.

FYI: you can call the base class method out of the child class method too, if you want to, for common behaviour.

Maybe check this link as well: [tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/)